# Does apache beam has its own native runner or is built over some other API like Spark etc?

Tags: apache-beam

Does apache beam has its own native runner or is built over some other API like Spark? Is beam some kind of wrapper over Apache Spark?

Comment: No , apache beam has no backend for handling the pipeline for large scales  .https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-262?focusedCommentId=15276724&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15276724

Answer (score 1):

Apache Beam is a programming model (an API) for defining data processing pipelines. It includes a set of SDKs for defining processing pipelines, and a set of runners for executing them.

Runners typically execute pipelines on an existing parallel processing engine, including Apache Apex, Apache Flink, Apache Spark, and Google Cloud Dataflow. Runners currently under development include Apache Gearpump, and Apache Storm/JStorm/Twitter Heron, with several more in the exploratory phase.

Apache Beam project includes the Direct Runner, which executes pipelines on the local machine. It is designed to validate that pipelines adhere to the Apache Beam model as closely as possible. Instead of focusing on efficient pipeline execution, the Direct Runner performs additional checks to ensure that users do not rely on semantics that are not guaranteed by the model.